# How does "import Database.Persist as X hiding (get)" from the yesod-sqlite template works

Tags: haskell, yesod, hspec, haskell-persistent

I am using the yesod-sqlite template and trying to use the `get` function from `Database.Persist` in a test.

Here is my code:

```
[Entity _ task] <- runDB $ selectList [TaskName ==. name] []
...
user <- runDB $ X.get (taskUserId task)
```

And the error I am getting:

```
my_project/test/Handler/TaskSpec.hs:47:29: error:
Not in scope: ‘X.get’
No module named ‘X’ is imported.
```

In the `TestImport.hs` file, I saw this line:

```
import Database.Persist      as X hiding (get)
```

To my understanding it should be hidding the `get` function from the HSpec module, so I could use `X.get` for database retrieving. I also tried with `Database.Persist.get` and just `get` with the same result.

So my doubt is: what that line in `TestImport.hs` is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The import line is importing everything in the `Database.Persist` module **except** `get`, optionally qualified.

If I'm understanding correctly and you want to import **only** `get` qualified, and everything else unqualified, you could use:

```
import Database.Persist hiding (get)
import qualified Database.Persist as X (get)
```

Comment: I didn't even know you *could* mix qualified imports with import lists